# "too few quotes" error message when trying to use foreach value as a string

Tags: string, foreach, stata

I'm trying to append panel data for seven files using a `foreach` loop.

I know the code in Stata to append and understand the `foreach` command.

This is the code I have, which I assume is correct:

```
use "C:\Users\main\Documents\German patent applications 1996.dta"

foreach k in 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002{
    append using "C:\Users\main\Documents\German patent applications "'k'".dta"  
}
```

It should append the data for all the seven files into one data set containing data for the years `1996-2002`.

However, when I run this code i get the error message:

> too few quotes
>       r(132)

I'm clearly trying to use the `k` value as a string in the filename so it can be appended.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: Assuming code is correct when there is an error message! Note carefully from @Pearly Spencer's reply that your punctuation around local macro `k` was wrong -- in addition to the more evident error over double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the file name is of the form:

```
German patent applications 1997.dta
```

The following works for me:

```
foreach k in 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002{
    display "C:\Users\main\Documents\German patent applications `k'.dta"
}

C:\Users\main\Documents\German patent applications 1997.dta
C:\Users\main\Documents\German patent applications 1998.dta
C:\Users\main\Documents\German patent applications 1999.dta
C:\Users\main\Documents\German patent applications 2000.dta
C:\Users\main\Documents\German patent applications 2001.dta
C:\Users\main\Documents\German patent applications 2002.dta
```